# How to access recorded video filepath in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

**when i stop recording that capture video store in gallery so how to fetch that video so that i upload that video on server **

```
import Camera from 'react-native-camera';

    <Camera
                captureMode={this.state.captureMode}
                captureAudio={this.state.captureAudio}
                captureTarget={this.state.captureTarget}
                ref="camera"
                style={styles.preview}>

   { toggle? <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>this._startRecord()}>
                           <Image style={styles.clickimage}
                             source={require('../images/icon_record_stop.png')} /> 
                      </TouchableOpacity>
            : <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>this._endVideo()}>
                  <Image style={styles.clickimage}
                             source={require('../images/clickimage.png')} /> 
              </TouchableOpacity>
            }
      </Camera>


     _startRecord() {
      this.refs.camera.capture({mode: Camera.constants.CaptureMode.video})
        .then((data) => alert(data))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      }

_endVideo() {
     this.refs.camera.stopCapture()
    .then((response) => {                                      
               alert(response);   

         // so here what i do for fetching video file path for upload           
    }
```

i just what to upload that recorded video on server....

Comment: Which component you use, `react-native-camera`?

Comment: import Camera from 'react-native-camera';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read path from `data.path`, and then you can open file with [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs).

From [document](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera#captureoptions-promise):

> path: Returns the path of the captured image or video file on disk

```js
_startRecord() {
  this.refs.camera.capture({mode: Camera.constants.CaptureMode.video})
    .then((data) => {
      var path = data.path;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much i get path but how to store that video on firebase storage?

Comment: sorry I know nothing about firebase. maybe start a new question?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Since you have local path, you can then load binary data from it, upload to firebase and you will have your URL.

Comment: As mentioned in answer, you can read the file with react-native-fs.